# How does differentiate between Serialized data class and normal Serialized class?

Tags: android, kotlin

While writing code for RecyclerView to [get data](https://github.com/b-Istiak-s/simple-recyclerview-retrofit-kotlin/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/simple_recyclerview/model/Contacts.kt) I figured out there's a [data class](https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-mars-photos/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/marsphotos/model/MarsPhoto.kt) in Kotlin.

Following codes are taken from two different projects which are linked above.

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class MarsPhoto(
    val id: String,
    @SerialName(value = "img_src")
    val imgSrc: String
)
```

```kotlin
class Contacts {
    @SerializedName("country")
    private val country:String? = null

    fun getCountry():String?{
        return country
    }
}
```

I know that both classes are doing same job. So what does differentiate them? I also wonder in the `MarsPhoto` data class how they can get the `id` without declaring `SerialName` just the way they did for `imgSrc`. (I am just on the way to learning kotlin now, so I'm absolute beginner).

Answer (score 1):

Basically for "data" class the compiler automatically derives the following members from all properties declared in the primary constructor:

equals()/hashCode() pair

toString() of the form "MarsPhoto(id=1, imgSrc=asdf)"

componentN() functions corresponding to the properties in their order of declaration.

copy()

You can read a lot more at [enter link description here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html)

On the SerializedName part of your question. if you are dealing with Gson lib by default it is using fields name as "SerializedName". And only if you want to use something different then field name, you can use SerializedName annotation and pass your custom value there. But usually, everybody just writes @SerializedName() with duplication of field names as value for every field.

It's a good idea if you are receiving and Serializing data from server from Json. Because Backend developers can use a bad keys in response, which you don't want to use in your code, so @SerializedName will be the only place where you will have to see this key, and you can name your fields however you like.

Comment: On my second part of the question, as you can see that the id is declared like this : `val id: String,` so if an id is sent from server then it won't be accessible by the `variable`. So I will have to use `SerializedName` or `SerialName` for that also, or data class has something special for what we don't have to use `SerializedName` or `SerialName`. I have found another beautiful explanation out [there](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z6xj7hta7Ac)

Answer (score 0):

@Serializable used to mark class as serializable to disk or like into a file( alternative is Parcel able in android)  special useful in case of process death or configuration changes  and @SerializedName("country") used for json parsing when u receive the response from server

Answer (score 0):

You get the `id` without `@SerializedName` because the JSON property field is the same as your variable name, but `imgSrc` and `img_src` is not. Still, even if they are the same, you should always use `@SerializedName`, because your variable names could be converted to random letters during code optimization, and obfuscation.